# How to trace conversation: Git gui tool - Git

Tags: git, shell, interface, qgit

Searching through headlines of Questions potentially related but raised previously did not result in helpful matches.
As still not comfortable with Git shell-based interface currently myself uses mainly Git gui tools. However, I do not need Git nor use it for active version control. The need is rather to browse the history generated by folks in public repos, or theirs clones in my private storage.
My current favorite is qgit. Others do not perform in satisfying way, or do
not feature the needed functions.
Me believes I could better understand what are the reasons of dissatisfying results of my interaction with qgit, or other, in plotting history graph if I only could examine the dialog/conversation the gui tool holds with Git.
**Q.1**
Any trace possibility available at the level of Git shell-based interface (so to be tool-neutral and applicable with every tool)?
**Q.2**
Does qgit support such tracability?

**I want to use git graph. tool of my choice. User is interacting with the graph. tool, not with git directly. Most user's requests translate to requests sent from graph. tool to Git through the used interface (shell, compilable API, other). Git is responding through same connection interface. I want to see that conversation.**

Didn't find the answer to my question in `man git`, nor in `git help log`, nor in my repo's `.git` sub-directory.

I see, possibly two quite independent points are mixed up in my inquiry. Sorry for this.
-) which kind of Git's interface the gui tool is using (shell, compilable API, yet other)
-) tracing the addressed dialog at the same connection channel
I use namely wording "shell-based inteface" which deduces the connection gui-tool to Git through was shell-based, which must not always be true. Please treat my description accordantly. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "tracabliity"? You mean to view commit messages and view the tree?

Comment: By the term "such tracability" I mean the possibility to trace the dialog/conversation the qgit holds with Git via latter's shell-based interface.

Answer (score 1):

As for Git's interface (shell-based, other) the addressed tracability does not seem to exist. No signs of that's existence are to be found in git help (e.g. git log), nor in git's man page, nor in the .git sub-directory of a repo.
As for Git gui tools the answer seems to be tool specific. As for qgit the searched tracability does not seem to exist too.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would like to view a Git repositories commit messages and tree on the terminal using the Git command-line client.

There are many approaches for this but a good built-in approach is to use the `--graph` option:

```
cd /your/git/repo
git log --graph
```

This will put you in a type of pager program (probably [`less`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/less.htm)) and you can scroll through the results using the arrow keys and exit from this mode using `q`.

The information you can glean on the command-line will be the same that you get from a GUI tool like `qgit`.

The GUI tool may be convenient in some ways, but undoubtedly you'll have more power using the command-line.

[This](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History) is a very good article which provides more information about visualizing your repo on the command-line.

**EDIT:**
As for discovering the commands that `qgit` it using behind the scenes, I didn't find anywhere that it is actually logging out it's commands, but some inspiration can be derived from looking through it's [source code](http://repo.or.cz/w/qgit4/redivivus.git).

Specifically, [git.cpp](http://repo.or.cz/qgit4/redivivus.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/src/git.cpp). Search for "`run(`" and "`cmd(`" to see the Git commands it is building up such as:

```
        QString baseCmd("git log --topo-order --no-color "

#ifndef Q_OS_WIN32
                        "--log-size " // FIXME broken on Windows
#endif
                        "--parents --boundary -z "
                        "--pretty=format:%m%HX%PX%n%cn<%ce>%n%an<%ae>%n%at%n%s%n");
```

Comment: I want use git graph. tool of my choice. User is interacting with the graph. tool, not with git directly. Most user's requests translate to requests sent from graph. tool to Git through the used interface (shell, compilable API, other). Git is responding through same connection interface. I want to see that conversation.

Comment: @Na13-c oh...you want to see the commands that qgit is running internally to generate it's content?

Comment: Exact! That's the point. However, Optimally to see the dialog whichever graph. tool is used.

Comment: Yes, I am familiarized with the book Pro Git and its chapter 2.3. Examples given there do not correlate with my current needs (see description above). Thus my take of additional tools - graph. interface.

Comment: As the wide recommendations made in answers and comments here git log seems to be the best way even if there are some burdens on get comfortable with it. It is practically not possible that a git graphic interface app covers all git functionalities, here of git log, sniffing the dialog between app and git seems to be for most existing apps a nice-to-have feature.